# How to simulate "not in" with a join in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I have two relation table "demande" and "reponse" which are linked and I'd like to retrieve all the lines of "demande" not in "reponse".

I try this with a join :

```
$select = new Select ();

$select->columns(array("id"));
$select->from ("demande" );
$select->where->lessThan("dateArretMarche",$stringDate );
$select->join(
    array("rep" => 'reponse'), // table name,
    'demande.id = rep.id_demande',array(),  
    $select::JOIN_RIGHT);

$select ->where->isNull("rep.id");//<== it doesn't work
```

But I can't select "null" lines". 
I guess it's possible with "not in" but Zend Framework provide only "in" predicate.

Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just include it in the query? Like this:

```
$select ->where('rep.id IS NULL');
```

Comment: it works, but why `$select->where->isNull('rep.id')` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `isNull` condition.So do you need to use with `Predicate`.Try with following code.

```
    $select->where(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\IsNotNull("rep.id")
            )
    );
```